# Changing class of an child element on hover of parent using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two divs. *Parent div* has class `.parentClass` and *child div* has class `.childClass` . There is one more class `.hababa` which is not applied to either divs.

Is it possible to change class of *child div* from `.childClass` to `.hababa` when I hover on a *parent div*.  **without using javascript**

**note-** I don't want to copy contents of `.hababa` like-

```
.parentClass:hover .childClass{
   //contents of .hababa
}
```

I just want to change class of *child div*.

Comment: No, you cannot change an element's class using only CSS. You will need to set the individual properties inside `.childClass:hover{  }`

Comment: I don't think so. One typical solution would be adding a class on hovering the element via JavaScript.

Comment: Not possible with `css`. You need to use `javascript` or `jQuery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer, **NO**(ish)

However, assuming you want to do this for styling purposes only (and not DOM manipulation) if you look at the logic of what you're trying to accomplish- you are trying to replace one class with another when you hover.

Is this not the same as doing, e.g.:

```
.parentClass:hover .childClass, .hababa{
   /* this means that the child class styling matches hababa on hover */
}
```

The above basically accomplishes the same thing as removing one class in favour of the other- with the exception of not removing any styling rules that the child class has which `hababa` does not, so arent overwritten.

In which case you will also need a rule to reset these, e.g.:

```
.parentClass:hover .childClass{
   /* remove any rules not shared with hababa */
}
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mh5Pp/2/)

Comment: but you still have to write styles in there too....`parentClass:hover .childClass, .hababa {
    background:blue;
    color:yellow;
    font-weight:bold;
}`

Comment: it is otherwise not possible unfortunately